# Spurious sum() Overflow on WinPython 3.3.2 64bit (Win 8.1 64bit)

Tags: python, types, sum, 64-bit, overflow

On Win 8.1 64bit, using WinPython 3.3.2 64bit [only on THIS version!] solving the Euler Problem #10, 
the two functions prob10 and prob10i yield different results:

```
def no_primes():
    return {j for i in range(2,5000) for j in range(i*2, 10000000,i)}

def primes():
    return \[i for i in range(2,10000000) if i not in no_primes()\]  


def prob10():    
        return int(sum(list(map(float,\[i for i in primes() if i<2000000\]))))

def prob10i():    
        return sum(\[i for i in primes() if i<2000000\])][1]
```

In other words, if you convert them to float before summing, the result is correct.
If you just sum them, the result is less than 1% of the correct result (overflow?).

All numbers involved are way, way below sys.maxsize, so WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?
Is there effectively some kind of sys.maxint  [which does not exist in Python3]?

Comment: Can you post the code for your `primes` function? Maybe it is giving some weird results ...

Comment: @BasSwinckels: Good point. Maybe `primes` is a generator that uses some global instead of local state, or something?

Comment: As a side note: Why all the extra complexity of `list(map(float, [i for…])))` instead of just `[float(i) for i…]`? (For that matter, why build a list, much less two of them, instead of just summing the iterator from `map`, or from a genexpr?)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that it's the float version that's correct and the int version that's incorrect? The *opposite* should be the case. How do you know the correct value?

Comment: Thanks for comments. This is the generator:
def no_primes(): return {j for i in range(2,5000) for j in range(i*2, 10000000,i)}

def primes(): return [i for i in range(2,10000000) if i not in no_primes()]

Comment: But whatever primes() does, it will not explain the difference between adding as float and adding as int :-(  The FLOAT version is correct (according to Euler and 100.000 participants), the INT version is incorrect. Looks very much like an int overflow. But then it should return a NaN, not a random number :-(
Does not look like state. If you call both functions alternatingly, they always have their individual same results.
>> sum(map()) for some reason gives me a map object, not a number.

Comment: Python ints *do not overflow*, period. Floats lose precision (can't represent every whole number, for example only even ones), but only when going beyond 2^52. Also, NaN is a *float* value, not an int value. And `sum(map())` does *not* give a `map` object. Your observations are quite outlandish. Please give a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: For the record, I get exactly the same output for both. And when omitting the `list()` around the `map()`, too. Unless you can give a program that reproduces the weirdness you describe, I'll chalk it all up to hallucinations on your part ;-)

Comment: @delnan: Are you using WinPython 3.3.2 64bit ??  

I am on Windows 8.1 64bit. Maybe that makes a difference...
Obviously I am not assuming that ALL versions of Python are broken!

Comment: I'm on a 64 bit Windows 7, using a 32 bit build of Python 3.2.2 (is your Python 64 bit too or only your OS?). Again, I think the best way to process is for you to create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem, at least for your installation. Then I and others can (1) verify that you didn't just dream this, and (2) debug the problem.

Comment: The IDLE Python 3.3.3 64bit does NOT exhibit this sum() overflow, for example.

Comment: @user3225173 You're making it damn hard to help you diagnose the problem. **Please** add a self-contained Python program that anyone can run, without copy-pasing various parts together (and risk inadvertedly fixing the bug along the way), that exhibits the problem for you. Then we can get to figuring out why it happens.

Comment: The bottom line is that __WinPython 3.3.2 64bit__ (NOT any other version) seems to be seriously broken. If someone would like to reproduce the problem on THIS VERSION, it would be highly appreciated. Also I would be grateful for a link to WinPython 3.3.3 64bit, ie. the NEXT version.

Comment: This bottom line is what I doubt. The odds of this specific version, and non other, being so deeply broken seem so low that I would like to rule out things like: (1) You made a silly typo somewhere once and are chasing a ghost. (2) There's a genuine bug in *your* code. (3) *I* did something wrong trying to reproduce your problem, and it actually exists in my version too and is only triggered by the very specific way your code is written. Also, I would prefer not to copy & paste several code snippets again when I finally get around to trying it with WinPython 3.3.2 64 bit.

Comment: @delnan: your (1) and (2) are quite unlikely, since both functions give the correct result under IDLE Python 3.3.3 64bit. The strange behavior of sum(map()) is another indicator that the 3.3.2 version is broken.

Comment: Two more questions: Are you using WinPython 3.3.2.3 or some earlier version - if so, which exactly? And does optimizing (many million times) `primes` by calculating `no_primes()` *once* - instead of each time the condition in the list comprehension is checked - make the bug go away? If not, I'd rather try reproducing the optimized version, because the code in the question takes *ages*.

Comment: I tried WinPython 3.3.2.3 64 bit (interpreter, not IDLE). The un-optimized `primes` was still running after about an hour, so I killed it and tried the aforementioned optimization (`def primes(): np = no_primes(); return [i for i in range(2,10000000) if i not in np]`). I got the same (correct) result from `prob10()` and `prob10i()`. I have to conclude that your observation is BS and there is no such bug in any version of any Python distribution. Please triple-check whether you yourself can reproduce this bug on your own machine.

Comment: @user3225173 ping. Anything new? Did you manage to reproduce the error on your machine?

Comment: @delnan: I cannot seem to share your optimism about Python integers not overflowing. For example I got this error message: Warning (from warnings module): RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars   

while trying to execute this:
def mydot(a,b):
    import numpy as np
    a=np.array([0,0,904741])
    b=np.array([0,0,1381221])
    return list(p*q for p,q in zip(a,b))    
      
    return list(p*q for p,q in zip(a,b))

Result is [0, 0, -188214375]  (negative number as product of two positive ones). Wish I could post a screenshot...

Comment: @user3225173 NumPy arrays don't contain Python integers, they contain fixed-width machine integers. `p` and `q` are instances of `numpy.int32` or some similar type. Until you create (and share!) a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem, I'm going to assume you are wasting my time by either being hopelessly incompetent at debugging or willfully trolling. I'd be glad if you proved me wrong, but that's the only conclusion I can draw from the past interactions.